# input() not working in a .exe file in python

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

`input` gives me an error everytime I try to start the .exe file

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working.py", line 58, in <module>
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

I tried to make a little afk bot and it worked in my terminal so I decided to do it in an .exe file which gives me an error everytime I try to execute it.

I expected that the .exe file open the terminal and that the code works perfectly fine, but sadly it didn't.

**Line 58:**

```
input('Moechtest du wirklich das programm starten, wenn ja druecke die ENTER Taste!')
```

I'm using Python 3.11 and `auto-py-to-exe` to convert .py to .exe file.

Comment: Are you opening a cmd prompt and running your exe in it, or are you double clicking your exe?

Comment: So it is working from a terminal, but not without a terminal? Where exactly do you expect to type in the result without a terminal? (in which window)? That error message says exactly that: there is no where to take input from.